# Can I downgrade the database version of DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have DNN installation on SQL Server 2008 (R2).
I am changing my hosting to another web hosting company where SQL Server 2005 is the only option.
Right now I have db backup (.bak file) & all DNN folders. Is it possible to downgrade the database version to SQL Server 2005?
If yes, can someone jot down the steps for me?
If not, whats the backup plan if I have to stick with SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413699/restore-sql-server-2008-db-to-sql-server-2005

I highly suggest Redgate Tools for this. SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare should do the trick.

Comment: After downgrading the database, and pointing connection string to it, would DotNetNuke work fine? Or do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: That should work just fine. ADO.NET doesn't really care 2005 vs. 2008. What really matters is whether the stored procedures are using 2008-only functionality, and it is my understanding that DNN SP's are backwards compatible to 2005